what are the rules to write a 00-installer-config.yaml file when the server is connected via wifi?
I am sure I will look stupid but I could not find anything that works on the net.
Any help will be appreciated, the objective is to have a static IP adress.
ip -a gives this:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:f4:bb:5a:a4:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:39:c4:5a:ed:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.23/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
       valid_lft 85658sec preferred_lft 85658sec
    inet6 2a01:cb18:86e8:8f00:af3b:1ddb:bddf:b21e/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 1781sec preferred_lft 581sec
    inet6 2a01:cb18:86e8:8f00:8726:a333:495b:f2f3/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1781sec preferred_lft 581sec
    inet6 fe80::b6bf:3baa:48c0:e9b4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


I tried this (among others):
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wlp4s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.200/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    eth0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.200/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

but, of course it failed
Thank you for your help
